# How do you use ANY using psycopg2?

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, psycopg2

Using psycopg2, I want to do an update statement using a list of elements:

```
cursor.execute("UPDATE mytable SET mycol=2 WHERE name=ANY(%s) RETURNING id", 
                                    tuple(keywords))
```

where keywords is a list of strings, since `name` is a varchar column. However, I get:

```
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

How should I do the request?

Comment: how does keywords look like, and the problem is that multiple keys will be lookng for multiple %s which you don't have. you need alt least as many s% for any word and if you have only one you still need a tuple with tow dimensons

Comment: By reading the docs [List/Array adaptation](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#adapt-list) and [Passing parameters](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries). And understanding what `tuple()` does: `l = [1, 2, 3]  tuple(l) (1, 2, 3)`. Then you would end up with `..., [keywords])`.

Comment: @nbk keywords is a list of string as I said, e.g., keywords = ["house", 'beach", "yatch"]

Comment: Which when you do `tuple(["house", "beach", "yatch"]) ` results in `('house', 'beach', 'yatch')` and the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @Adrian.

It should be:

```
cursor.execute("UPDATE mytable SET mycol=2 WHERE name=ANY(%s) RETURNING id", 
                                    tuple([keywords]))
```

Comment: You don't need the `tuple`, just do as I showed in my first comment, `..., [keywords]`. The parameters can come from any sequence of values so a list of list is acceptable.